# Improving HTTP requests performance - PySpark on Databricks (Requests module)

Tags: python, pyspark, http-headers, python-requests, databricks

I'm trying to get http response codes for 25k links using PySpark (Databricks), but it is taking forever: 14 hours(!)

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def response_api_call(url):
    try: 
        r = requests.head(url, timeout = 30)
        response = r.status_code
        return response
    except:
        return "Error"

response_api_call = udf(response_api_call, StringType())

links_df = links_df.withColumn('responseCode', response_api_call(links_df.link))
```

Is there something wrong with my code, or is there an easy way to parallelize it/improve performance?

Comment: I don't think this is specific to pyspark, but then again I don't know much about it, but I am pretty sure making 25k HTTP requests in a loop and returning the status code will be slow, especially with a timeout of 30 seconds

Comment: Seems like you're averaging ~2 sec per link. It's likely the overhead of the HTTP request. Are you caching your DataFrame (`links_df.cache()`) before calling the UDF? That may help improve performance.